# how to show a Component in React and renew its lifecycle each time its showed?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I just started node.js and react, I was curious how to create a chat app with socket.io so I followed few tutorials on how to create rooms, joining/leaving and messaging in the room. I used React Context to pass one socket instance.

I can create rooms, join them, leave them. The problem I got is that when I join another room and try to send a message, I get this warning:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. when rendering a component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Can you please give me some advice on about how I should rethink to rewrite React with `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` functions for this case?

I'd like to add these details to understand what I'm trying to do:
- homepage where users can create rooms
- rooms are spawned as 2 buttons, 1 to show the Chatroom (join the room) and the other to close the Chatroom (leave the room)
- users can join the Chatroom and send messages

client side (Home.js)

```
class Home extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);

  this.state = {
   room: "",
   rooms: [],
   chat: false
  };

  this.creatingRoom = this.creatingRoom.bind(this);
  this.joinRoom = this.joinRoom.bind(this);
  this.leaveRoom = this.leaveRoom.bind(this);

  this.props.socket.on("createRoom", function(room) {
   addRoom(room);
  });

  const addRoom = room => {
   this.setState({ rooms: [...this.state.rooms, room] });
  };
 };

 creatingRoom(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.socket.emit("creatingRoom", {
   room: this.state.room
  });

  this.setState({ room: "" });
 };

 joinRoom(e) {
  let room = e.target.value;
  this.props.socket.emit("joinRoom", room);

  this.setState({
   chat: true
  });
 };

 leaveRoom(e) {
  let room = e.target.value;
  this.props.socket.emit("leaveRoom", room);

  this.setState({
   chat: false
  });
 };

 render() {
  return (

   <React.Fragment>

    {this.state.chat === true ? (
      <ChatroomWithSocket />
    ) : (
      <h1> no chatroom </h1>
    )}

    <div>
      <h1> Create your room </h1>
    </div>

    <div>
      <form>
        <textarea
          name="room"
          placeholder="Write.."
          value={this.state.room}
          onChange={ev => this.setState({ room: ev.target.value })}
        />
        <button onClick={this.creatingRoom}>
          Create
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4> Rooms </h4>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.rooms.map((room, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>
                <button href="#" onClick={this.joinRoom} value={room.room}>
                  Join {room.room}
                </button>
                <button href="#" onClick={this.leaveRoom} value= 
                 {room.room}>
                  Leave {room.room}
                </button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

   </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
}

const HomeWithSocket = props => (
 <SocketContext.Consumer>
  {socket => <Home {...props} socket={socket} />}
 </SocketContext.Consumer>
);
```

client side (Chatroom.js)

```
class Chatroom extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
  message: "",
  messages: []
 };

 this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);

 this.props.socket.on("receiveMessage", function(data) {
  addMessage(data);
 });

 const addMessage = data => {
  this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, data] });
 };
}

  sendMessage(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.props.socket.emit("sendMessage", {
   message: this.state.message
   });

   this.setState({ message: "" });
  }

render() {
 return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="messages">
      {this.state.messages.map((message, key) => {
        return <li key={key}>{message.message}</li>;
      })}
    </div>

    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.sendMessage}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Message"
          value={this.state.message}
          onChange={ev => this.setState({ message: ev.target.value })}
        />
        <button type="submit"> 
          Send
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
   </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
}

const ChatroomWithSocket = props => (
 <SocketContext.Consumer>
  {socket => <Chatroom {...props} socket={socket} />}
 </SocketContext.Consumer>
);
```

server side (index.js)

```
var rooms = [];

io.on("connection", function(socket) {

 socket.on("creatingRoom", function(room) {
  rooms.push(room);
  io.emit("createRoom", room);
 });

 socket.on("joinRoom", function(newRoom) {
  socket.join(newRoom);
  socket.room = newRoom;
 });

 socket.on("leaveRoom", function() {
  socket.leave(socket.room);
 });

 socket.on("sendMessage", function(data) {
  io.emit("receiveMessage", data);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means what it says, a possible memory leak.

From my suspicions, it could be from the socket connection. See it this way..

In the `componentDidMount`, you set a socket connection. If you are leaving the component without closing the socket connection, you're bound to receive this error. I'm not sure what exactly you're doing, but try closing the socket in the `componentWillUnmount` to see if it works.

If it does, consider creating the socket in a component that doesn't get destroyed when navigating, or store the socket connection in Redux

Comment: thank you for your fast reply! I added in the post what I'm trying to do. The thing I don't understand about your suggestion is why do I have to close the socket connection? Because it's the socket connection which allows me to create room, join/leave room, send messages in the Chatroom ?

Comment: Socket connection **may** hold up the global space. And when it does, when the component unmounts, the global space may essentially be calling a variable which no longer exists, hogging memory... Lemme know if you get me

Comment: I get your point, so it is like when I close the Chatroom, and then I join another, the socket connection is trying to call this component which no longer exists? How would the componentWillUnmount fix this?

Comment: More or less, yes. If you have Redux installed, consider putting the socket object in it. It is, after all, an object